# Sprite generation Compass/SASS

Tags: sass, compass-sass, sprite

I'm using Compass Sprite helpers in a project which works great. However the generation of the sprite adds quite a few seconds to the project compile time and most of the time I do not need it regenerated.

Is there a way to turn off the sprite generation and get compass to use the last generated file?

I'm using CodeKit and I'll be easily confused by much talk of command line / Ruby!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a CodeKit issue which is getting fixed:
https://github.com/bdkjones/CodeKit/issues/297

Until then I am using a workaround detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518037/codekit-compass-vs-less-compilation-when-spriting).

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried it, and for me Compass does not recompile my sprites unless i modify the contents of the sprites folder:

```
$ compass compile
unchanged images/sexy-sce786a2ec5.png
overwrite stylesheets/screen.css
```

Try compiling your project with the `compass` command line tool instead of CodeKit. If it works out, please check that CodeKit uses Compass to compile your project and not vanilla SASS.

Comment: takes ages to check the unchanged status of the images though .... so I don't understand why I just can't have a hard setting to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if `compass compile` *with no other arguments* (as per Andrey 'lolmaus's answer) does not cause this, but if there are any arguments at all it sets the `:force` option to true, and one of the consequences of that is that sprites are forcibly recreated.

That seems like crazy behaviour?

For the moment I've edited `lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb` (specifically, in my case, `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/compass-0.12.4/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb`) and commented out the `parser.options[:force] = true` line in the `parse_arguments!` function at the end of that file.

(note the `unless arguments.empty?` condition)

That seems to have disabled sprite generation entirely (i.e. even when you need it), but I can enable it manually with `compass compile --force ...`

That's certainly good enough for me.