# Compass watch with sprites slow

Tags: sass, compass-sass, sprite

I have a relatively big sass project with quite a few sprites.  When I have compass watch running and make a change, the project takes a few seconds to compile because checking the sprites takes a long time. The sprites are NOT actually getting overridden or anything (unless of course I change the images) but just the process of checking each image takes a while.  Is there a way to run compass watch while ignoring sprites just to speed things up? Then if I want to change sprites I can just manually compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been searching for a solution to this as well. A not great (but working solution) can be found here: [Codekit Compass vs Less compilation when spriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518037/codekit-compass-vs-less-compilation-when-spriting)

Basically I have a sprites file allSprites.sass which creates allSprites.css. I then put that into _sprites.scss and import that into my main.sass file.

If I could automate moving the allSprites.css into the _sprites.scss on change of the allSprites.sass file my life would be complete =)

Comment: you can use GruntJs or Guard to merge allSprites.css into whatever you want on change to _allSprites.scss